# I need some help with properties of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences of real numbers. Verify the Following holds.
$$ \limsup x_n +\liminf y_n \le \limsup\,(x_n+y_n).$$ This is what I have tried but I am not quite sure if it is correct.
$\text{Fix } K>1. \text{ Let }L=\inf_{1\le i \le k}y_i$. Now 
$$
\sup_{1 \le i \le k}(x_i+y_i)\ge \sup_{1\le i \le k}(x_i+L)=L+\sup_{1\le i \le k} x_i = 
\inf_{1\le i \le k} y_i +\sup_{1\le i \le k} x_i.
$$ 
Now we take the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and we have the desired result. Does this look ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are allowed to use the following properties:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (-x_n) =-\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n,
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (x_n+y_n)\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty} y_n,
$$
then
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n &= \limsup_{n\to\infty} (x_n+y_n-y_n)\le
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (x_n+y_n)+\limsup_{n\to\infty} (-y_n) \\
&= \limsup_{n\to\infty} (x_n+y_n)-\liminf_{n\to\infty} y_n.
\end{align}

Comment: wow your version is much nicer than mine:) tyvm